# How do I manage state better in front-end tests

Tags: selenium, test-automation

I write a lot of front-end tests, and the tests fail really often. To be honest, they're hard for me to write. I feel like I have to do a lot of work keeping track of the state of the page. It seems like every function I write is the opposite of a pure function. There are so many side-effects. I get stale reference exceptions and null pointer exceptions all the time.

For example, I say `comment.clickLike()`, but I'm no longer on the page containing that comment (stale reference).

Or I'll say `findElement(".comment:eq(0)").clickLike()`, and I'll get a NPE because I'm no longer on the page so I end up not finding the comment.

There are other factors too. `findElement(".comment:eq(0)").clickLike()` could fail because one of the front-end devs decided to change the class of comments to `post-comment` or something.

What are some good practices to make the tests I write safer? Is there a way to design page-object interactions that makes them have less side effects? Is there a way to find objects on the page even if their selectors change over time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of possible strategies that you can employ.

1. Reset the page so that your test is always starting at the same page state.
2. Reduce the number of state transitions you make on the page.
3. Push as much application logic as you possibly can out of the page to somewhere else.

Comment: I don't have any control over the code in the actual website, so can I do anything about number 3?